# How to find the base of an isosceles triangle with the two equal sides and their medians known

Tags: geometry, triangles

I know, that the two equal sides are equal to $4\sqrt{10}$ and the medians to each of these sides are equal to $6\sqrt{3}$. I feel like, there's some information missing. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: There is enough information here to find the solution. Are you familiar with Heron's formula?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a corollary of the [Apollonius Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27s_theorem) to show that the length of the median onto side $a$ is $$m_a = \frac12 \sqrt{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}$$
and since $a=b=4\sqrt{10}$ and $m_a = 6\sqrt{3}$ you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Let the triangle be $ABC$ with $AB=AC$ and $M$ the midpoint of $AC$.

Use the cosine formula on each of $AMB,BMC$ using the angle at $M$ in each case. [Note that the two cosines have equal magnitude and opposite signs.]